# Angular 6 CLI installation

Tags: angular, angular6, command-line-interface

I am trying to install the Angular 6 CLI but I get this message
C:\Users\baigk\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\baigk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng
npm WARN rollback Rolling back node-pre-gyp@0.10.3 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\baigk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

- @angular/cli@7.3.0
  updated 1 package in 3.863s

Comment: what was the command you used to install it ?

Comment: I reinstalled the npm using >npm install npm -g. Then I am getting this error                 C:\Users\baigk>npm install -g @angular/cli
C:\Users\baigk\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\baigk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cli@7.3.0
updated 1 package in 10.523s

Comment: I used npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: what do you get when you do: `npm -v` and `node -v` in the command line ?

Comment: C:\>npm -v
6.7.0

C:\>node -v
v10.15.0

Comment: I used git bash to create and run the projects and it all seems to work now. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

EPERM: operation not permitted happens usually when command not runned with Administrator or Antivirus not allowing it. Turn off Antivirus and run same command as Administrator again.